# Cordova platform windows and wp8 difference

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing a new cordova app which should be avaible for android, ios and windowshpones. The problem is that you can add cordova platform windows and cordova platform wp8. What is the difference? Is the platform windows not for all windowsphones? Do I have to add another one (wp8)? Also are there more wp8 phones than windows phones so is it enough to just add wp8?

Hope someone can expain me that ;)

Comment: cordova platform windows means it's for windows system 8.1 and windows system 10 desktop application and wp8 measn windows phone 8 and 8.1 and 10. if you are making only phone applicaiton i preffer add with wp8 only. Because in cordova platform windows has more then one platforms inside it for windows machine, windows phone as well so it will be confusing. so better add wp8 only.

Comment: ok thanks but that means when I add wp8 not all windowsphones are supported right?

Comment: yes support for all windows phone

Comment: Thanks for the answers ;)

Comment: I add as answer please mark as answer so other can also get solution of their confusion. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cordova platform windows means it's for **windows system 8.1** and windows system 10 desktop application and **wp8** means **windows phone 8 and 8.1 and 10**. if you are making only phone applicaiton i preffer add with wp8 only. Because in cordova platform windows has more then one platforms inside it for windows machine, windows phone as well so it will be confusing. so better add wp8 only.

**WP8** support all windows phone device.